# is there any expiration time to a password in Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to know if there is any expiration time to a password in Firebase Auth. I mean, if the user needs to change the password every couple of months or if that is not necessary because the password won't expire. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password of the user don't expire. But the user could change it whenever they want.